# C# .NET 4.6 equivalent of Unsafe.As

Tags: c#

What is a C# .NET 4.6 equivalent of this:

```
    public static float UnpackFloat32(this ulong value)
    {
        return Unsafe.As<ulong, float>(ref value);
    }
```

The Unsafe.As isn't available in 4.6.

Comment: Can you use `https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/` to achieve this?  It's compatible with 4.5+ and available at https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/

Comment: If I add that reference, the Unsafe.As becomes available - but the compiler isn't happy with the type.

Error CS7085 By-reference return type 'ref TTo' is not supported.

Comment: BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(v)) will do the same.  But do pause a bit at the wisdom of converting a 64-bit value to a 32-bit value, the upper 32-bits of the ulong value disappear into the bit-bucket.

Answer (score 6):

You might even implement it in earlier .NET versions without unsafe code by using a structure with explicit layout:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct FloatUlongConverter
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public float floatValue;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public ulong ulongValue;
}

public static ulong PackFloat32(this float value)
{
    var converter = new FloatUlongConverter();
    converter.floatValue = value;
    return converter.ulongValue;
}

public static float UnpackFloat32(this ulong value)
{
    var converter = new FloatUlongConverter();
    converter.ulongValue = value;
    return converter.floatValue;
}
```

Comment: Unsafe.As is a generic and you cannot use explicit cast on generics. For the primitive types used in the question it works though.